# resharper covariant array conversion - contradicting fix

Tags: c#, arrays, resharper, warnings

I have the following code:

```
private static DataTable MyMethod(DataTable oneColDataTable)
{
   DataTable result = new DataTable();

   foreach (DataRow row in oneColDataTable.Rows)
   {
       string[] newRow = row[0].ToString().Split(';'); // [1] Co-variant array conversion when object[]

       while (newRow.Length > result.Columns.Count)
       {
           result.Columns.Add(new DataColumn());
       }

       result.Rows.Add(newRow); // [2] Co-variant array conversion                
   }

   return result;
}
```

**Functionality of this code**

What I do here is to take a DataTable with one Column. In that Column I have content like this in multiple rows: "This;Is;the;first;row" - "This;Is;another;row;that;has;more;words";
I split this Information to then interprete the words as column-values for that row. Basically transforming it to a table with multiple rows, like this:

```
Content of my DataTable:
|This|Is|the    |first|row |   |    |     |
|This|Is|another|row  |that|has|more|words|
```

**Co-variant array conversion - The problem**

ReSharper warns me about a "Co-variant array conversion" at comment [2]. The Auto-Fix of resharper turns the "string[]" in the line of comment [1] to "object[]". But now it gives me the same Warning for line of comment [1]. Auto-Fixing this results in the code it had before, so its basically a very annoying loop.

I dont want to disable the warning with a comment beacuse I generally think thats a lazy and bad approach. but I dont see any other way to fix this. Am I doing something wrong in my code? Is there a way to fix this without suppressing or ignoring the warning?

Comment: It, in fact does. Split is returning strings while Rows.Add accepts just array of objects.

Comment: I'm looking on that right now with latest R# Ultimate and in case you do it as described by Smogen you really get message as mentioned. Not sure which versions you are testing with.

Comment: @HimBromBeere You have to read the text.  The fix for the second one changes the type to `object[]` on the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case your goal would be remove that warning message it's enough to change first line to produce array of objects instead of string.

```
object[] newRow = row[0].ToString().Split(';').Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

But then it's question whether it's really necessary to design structure of table during enumeration of it's supposedly new rows or even whether such a change for sake of getting rid of messages may cost you some performance spent on `Cast<>` and enumeration

EDIT:
The thing is there is no real problem to be fixed. You're getting warning saying something *may* happen. It's also good to realize that R# warning doesn't mean it's definitely error, it's letting you know you should care about that part.

Imagine:

```
public static object[] GetTuples()
{
    return new Tuple<string, int>[10]; // R# warning here
}
public static void Test()
{
    object[] tuples = GetTuples();
    tuples[0] = new Tuple<string, int>("", 1);
    tuples[1] = ""; // this will crash process, but no R# Warnings here
}
```

Compared with your described scenario:

```
string[] parts = "some;string".Split(",");
table.Rows.Add(parts);
```

R# doesn't have power to differentiate between these two cases. The warning you're getting is totally mathematically correct. On the other hand you as developer know that it can't cause issue this warning is targeting because you know that code better than R# can. It's good to adopt idea that you're Lord of your code and R# is just useful source of hints - not vice versa.

It's totally normal enterprise code contains R# suppression on places where developers know it's safe while willing to have it enabled in other parts of code base.

As second edit:
Code I've posted is not in fact hiding any (even virtual) problem. It changes things happening from 'Type system point of view', while it may sound nearly same it's kinda 'big deal difference':
Originally you've created string[] - e.g. some entity capable to store strings
Then you've passed this array to method which expects `object[]` and does something with that. That means cast from `string[]` to `object[]` will happen. In program word it means I'm giving you object[], you may store there any System.object (e.g. everything inherited from that) but as explained it's not true.

Given fact we know what happens there we know it's OK (you can check DataTable.cs here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs
and be sure there will be no issue while `Add(object[] params))` does not modify input array as mentioned before - but R# does not know this piece of information.

After my change you're not doing that cast anymore. You're taking array of strings and by casting one-by-one to object you are creating whole new array - not just different type identity of you previous array. Hope this will help rather than confuse.

Btw. another **proper** solution is to disable this kind of warning, but it's not best way :)

Comment: Ah, with Juharrs comment I got it.

Comment: Sadly thats not what I was going for. Its just another way to suppress the warning, even if its technically without a comment but to me this is basically the same: I hid the problem, I didnt fix it.
Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: Yes, now I understand. You are right. I guess I will just suppress it with a comment since, now that you put it the way you did, thats what I feel like to be the proper way to deal with it. After all, as you said, its not 'wrong' to do what I do. Thank you!